# How to get same result multiple times with same inputs in laravel ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

i have different input fields and two of them are name_id[] and aussehen[] in the view.for example if user inputs two same value of (1,1) for the name_id and also (1,1) for the aussehen.when i run this query below.

```
$aussehen=Stufen::whereIN('name_id', $name_id)
         ->whereIN('stufe',$aussehen)
         ->get();
```

I get only one array when dd($aussehen). whereas i wanted to have two same arrays because user inputs the same values two times. But if user select two different values e.g (1,2) for name_id and (3,4) for aussehen then it shows the correct result with two arrays what i am expecting. Now is there anyway to get the same result even if user inputs the same values as much time as he wants?

Comment: Your request has any sense: you have two entries in your array if you change `name_id` and `ausshen` because it matches two different rows in db. If you match only one row (no matter how many times you provide the same values in input), result will always composed of only one row.

Comment: thanks for the answer.i were thinking the same.Is there anyway if i want to have the results two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Model::whereIn('id', [1, 1, 1, 1])->get()`, you tell your SQL database driver to run the query `SELECT * from model WHERE id IN (1, 1, 1, 1)` which yields the same results as `SELECT * FROM model WHERE id = 1`.

You should know that, besides heavy calculus, the database queries are one of the slowest things in a running PHP application. So you do not want to make multiple queries to the database.

My best guess will be:

```
$name_id = $request->input('name_id', []);
$aussehen = $request->input('aussehen', []);

$query = Stufen::whereIn('name_id', array_unique($name_id))
                ->whereIn('stufe', array_unique($aussehen))
                ->get()
                ->indexBy('name_id');
$collection = [];
foreach ($name_id as $nameId) {
    $collection[] = $results[$nameId];
}

return collect($collection);
```

What the code does is duplicates (remember, the eloquent models are objects, so it's only the reference) the unique indexed results from the query to a php array returned as a collection afterwards.

To extrapolate a little bit, you should return the `$query` directly into your view and use each object as many times as needed, so you will use only the `$query` and erase the `$collection` part, which is not very nice.